# cannot load Ruby gems for Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm trying to install Chef solo on a VPS. I've installed Ruby and ran the install command for the Chef gems, however, when I check the version of Chef, it says that it can't load the file. I'm following along with the Railscast on the topic http://railscasts.com/episodes/339-chef-solo-basics?view=asciicast, except that I also installed rbenv and Ruby 2.0.0 as a preliminary step.

Can you identify what the cause of this error is?

```
  root@Chef2:~# gem install chef ruby-shadow --no-ri --no-rdoc
    Successfully installed chef-11.4.4
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    Successfully installed ruby-shadow-2.2.0
    2 gems installed
    root@Chef2:~# rbenv rehash
    root@Chef2:~# chef-solo -v
    /root/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems/format (LoadError)
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/provider/package/rubygems.rb:34:in `<top (required)>'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/providers.rb:60:in `<top (required)>'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.4.4/bin/chef-solo:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/bin/chef-solo:23:in `load'
        from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/bin/chef-solo:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Chef 11 is the latest version of chef and is now packaged with an embedded copy of ruby. See the following documentation:

http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Installing+Chef+Client+and+Chef+Solo

Comment: Chef 11 is also shipped as a gem which is a valid way to setup and use it. In this case, it looks more like the rubygems installation is broken instead of chef.

Comment: @HolgerJust Ah yes, apologies I got confused with Vagrant which no longer supports a ruby gem install.

Answer (score 0):

What version of rubygem are you using?

Try using rubygems 1.8.25

Answer (score 0):

I think the original poster may have been running into a ruby-2.0/rubygems-2.0 issue like CHEF-3933 on chef 11.4.4  Those have been fixed by now.  Chef 11.10.0 supports ruby-2.1 + rubygems-2.2

Gem installs are highly discouraged if there's an omnibus installer.  The railscast is now very out of date.  Installation should be done with:

`curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | bash -s`